# Procedure created with compilation errors - but can't find error

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have a procedure but I can't find where the error is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_GRADE (
    STUDEN_ID IN VARCHAR2(6),
    SEC_ID IN NUMBER(6),
    NEW_GRADE IN CHAR (1)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE ENROLLMENT 
    SET grade = NEW_GRADE 
    WHERE s_id = STUDEN_ID AND c_sec_id = SEC_ID;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the schema for ENROLLMENT?

Comment: You can't specify the parameter sizes.  Change it to just VARCHAR2, NUMBER, and CHAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query ..

```
 select * from user_errors where name ='ADD_GRADE'
```

and youll have your error

Answer (score 3):

All respect goes to @MarkLeiber who spotted the error...

Try this instead:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE ADD_GRADE (
    STUDEN_ID IN VARCHAR2,
    SEC_ID IN NUMBER,
    NEW_GRADE IN CHAR
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE ENROLLMENT 
        SET grade = NEW_GRADE WHERE s_id = STUDEN_ID AND c_sec_id = SEC_ID;
END;
/
```